# use callback to allow multiple connections to socket?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, sockets, callback, asyncsocket

I am trying to create a VB.Net server program that has an external link to process data.  The server will wait on port 7878 for a request to be made from a client.  When the server receives a request it will send a string containing the state of all variables and send a string every second containing values for only changed variables.  The server does not need to receive any information from the client for processing.  I have successfully implemented everything with the exception of allowing for multiple requests at once.  The basic program looks like this:

```
Class Server
    Public Sub Main()
        'thread start for ListenForRequests
    End Sub

    Public Sub ListenForRequests()
        'code to set up socket
        'bind socket
        'listen
        Using newConnection as socket.accept()
            'do stuff
            newConnection.send'stuff
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class
```

Can anyone tell me a SIMPLE way to implement a callback for async code?  I think I need to move my 'do stuff and send stuff code into a new sub and fire a new thread upon socket.accept, but I can't figure out how to pass the newConnection through to a new thread.